# Jqm Modal not opening intermittently in IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqmodal

Jqm Modal seems to be working fine in all browser.However,sometimes it gives and error in IE 9
[image: Error while opening jqm modal]

Here is code for opening jqm Modal

```
  $('#AddDocumentModal').jqm({
    ajax: '@href',
    modal: false,
    overlay: 80,
    toTop: true,
    target: false,
    cache:false
});

$('a.AddDocumentTrigger').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();      
    $('#AddDocumentModal').jqm({
        ajax: this.href
    });
    $('#AddDocumentModal').jqmShow(this);
    return false;
});
```

jquery.jqGrid.src.js contains the code for Jqm Modal.

Comment: the line 4403 of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` don't contains code of `$.fn.jqm`. Which version of jqGrid and jQuery you use? Additionally I don't really understand which advantages has the usage of `ajax` parameter over direct calling of `jQuery.ajax`.

Comment: @Oleg jquery version - 1.8 , jqmModal version : r14

Comment: You should don't include any `jqModal.js` module. jqGrid contains already **fixed version** of jqmModal. In the comment you will see "07/06/2008 +r13", but it's **fixed version** of the file. So you should verify that you don't include any `jqModal.js` module and the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

What version of jqModal are you using? I recently rewrote the plugin and released R17.

Also I do not recommend re-initializing the modal element in your click handler. Try something like;

```
$('a.AddDocumentTrigger').live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();      
    $('#AddDocumentModal').jqmShow();
    return false;
});
```